# Where can I find rankings of soundtracks?

Tags: soundtrack

I adore the soundtrack by Hans Zimmer and Bryan Adams (with S MacLachlan) from the 2002 movie *Spirit: Stallion of the Cimarron*, but because I only chanced thereon, I fear ignorance and neglect of other excellent, but more obscure soundtracks.

I wish to find similar soundtracks and music, and so wish to resort to rankings of soundtracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Check out some film music reviews

Movie soundtrack reviews can be found at these sites:

- [Filmtracks](http://www.filmtracks.com/)
- [Movie-Wave](http://www.movie-wave.net/)
- [SoundtrackGeek](http://soundtrackgeek.com/)
- [FilmMusicMedia](http://www.filmmusicmedia.com/reviews)
- [MovieMusic](http://moviemusicuk.us/)
- [RateYourMusic](https://rateyourmusic.com/)

## 2. Check out some notable composers

Here are some the most popular film music composers:

- [John Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Williams)
- [James Horner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Horner)
- [James Newton Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Newton_Howard)
- [Howard Shore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Shore)
- [Hans Zimmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Zimmer)

## 3. Explore similar artists and music

Create an internet "radio station" based on a track, album, or artist you are interested in, and the station will play music that is similar to the music you chose.

- [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/music/radio/) [Radio](https://itunes.apple.com/us/radio)
- [Pandora Internet Radio](http://www.pandora.com/)

Answer (score 3):

My favourite place to browse music catalogues is [rateyourmusic.com](https://rateyourmusic.com) aka RYM.
Here is the [album](https://rateyourmusic.com/release/album/bryan_adams_hans_zimmer/spirit__stallion_of_the_cimarron/) you're talking about. You can find related albums from the same genre on the site, browse [top albums](https://rateyourmusic.com/customchart) ranked by users, sorted by year/genre. You can also read personal reviews, lists and ratings, which I think is the most interesting part of RYM.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should choose an artist (like Hans Zimmer) and listen to all of his works and make your own ranking, but if you like a website here it is: http://www.filmtracks.com/